# Adobe AIR : RemoteObject can't work with Worker?

Tags: air

I have issue with RemoteObject and worker , I have Adobe AIR Application develop with Flex Builder 4.6.

On the main part of the application , I can successfully execute RemoteObject, but the same code is not working in the worker

```
this.remoteobj  = new RemoteObject();
this.remoteobj.channelSet = this.channelSet;
this.remoteobj.destination = "WebDeltabank";
this.remoteobj.fExtractSMS.addEventListener("result", onfExtractSMS);
this.remoteobj.addEventListener("fault", onFault);

this.remoteobj.fExtractSMS();
```

Please Can someone help me ?

Comment: I want to add something, i am not able to found error, generated by the worker action script.

Answer (score 0):

According to Adobe AIR documentation:

"Several runtime APIs are not available in code running in a background worker. These primarily consist of APIs related to user input and output mechanisms, or operating system elements like windows and dragging. As a rule, for any API that isn't supported in all contexts, use the isSupported, available, and similar properties to check whether the API is available in the background worker context before attempting to use the API."

Comment: Thank For the Info, But this is not Mobile Application. it is a desktop application.

Comment: there is no big difference between AIR for mobile and Desktop, and its common if you have a concurrency in your application, you cannot call some API methods from Worker (for example: Unity3D works same way)